# Unity / How to add a shader to a material via c# script?

Tags: unity, shaders

I found already some things - but those seem not quite what I need. (perhaps outdated functions?)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html

here, it seems you can add a shader to a renderer:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Shader shader1;
    public Shader shader2;
    public Renderer rend;
    void Start() {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        shader1 = Shader.Find("Diffuse");
        shader2 = Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse");
    }
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            if (rend.material.shader == shader1)
                rend.material.shader = shader2;
            else
                rend.material.shader = shader1;

    }
}
```

well - i dont have a renderer. i only have a material.

and there is no "material.setShader" , only a material.setTexture"

sooo can anyone solve this mystery of how to add a shader to a material via script?

Comment: The example code you posted is quite obvious. It just accesses the material through the renderer. When you already have a reference to a material, you should be able to access its `.shader` property. Or is your *actual* question how to get a reference to a specific material in your project assets?

Comment: ...and that cube has no renderer? When it is a default cube you created from the Unity context menu then it should have one.

Comment: okay - so
I have a material (in my Assets)
I have a shader (in my Assets)
If I drag and drop the Shader in the Material - it works. I want to do the same thing in the c# skript. 

Now I have another material (created in code) and a Shader (created in code). 
The big question: how to add that shader inside that material?

Its gotta be 1 line of code.....

Comment: When you have a variable with your material called `theMaterial` and a shader with the variable `theShader`, it should just be `theMaterial.shader = theShader`. When that does not work, you should finally post your own code so we can see where your mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a reference to the material and the shader then you just need to do this: `myMaterial.shader = myShader;`  There's nothing more to it than that.

The [Unity Material API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html) says that the `shader` property is `public` so you can just use `=` instead of finding some "set" method.  There is an explicit "set" and "get" function for textures on materials because they can have more than one so they're identified with a name or id.

In your example with the renderer, it's just getting the material from the renderer and doing the same exact thing I mentioned above.  This code...

```
rend.material.shader = myShader;
```

has the same results as this code...

```
Material myMaterial = rend.material;
myMaterial.shader = myShader;
```